# "Runtime Error 13 : Type Mismatch" Error in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel work book in which for a Range of cells i want to check certain conditions like "Greater than 10", "Between 5 and 10" and color the values accordingly. The file also contain Blank values and NA (N and A Characters) values.
The Sample of Data can be found as in the below image.

[The Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Viv.png)

I used the below code.

```
For n= 1 o 10

For Each c In Worksheets(n).Range("A1:A10").Cells

If Abs(c.Value) > 10 Then
c.Interior.Color = vbRed
ElseIf Abs(c.Value) < 10 And Abs(c.Value) > 5 Then
c.Interior.Color = vbBlue
ElseIf c.Value = "NA" Or c.Value = " " Then
GoTo nofunction
End If
nofunction:
Next

Next n
```

While Running this code I am getting the error "Runtime Error 13 : Type Mismatch"

I believe the issue is with the condition ElseIf c.Value = "NA" Or c.Value = " " .

Can someone please help me in overcoming this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for numeric values first:

```
For n= 1 o 10
    For Each c In Worksheets(n).Range("A1:A10").Cells
        v = c.Value
        IfIsNumeric(v) Then
            If Abs(v) > 10 Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf Abs(v) < 10 And Abs(v) > 5 Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbBlue
            End if
        End If
    Next
Next n
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) This Worked Exactly on what i want !!